# Inlet of an ICE

Tags: engines

[image]
What is wrong with totally replacing the inlet of a piston engine with a surgical mask?As surgical masks get rid of about 80% of air impurities and dusts.

Comment: I want to reduce the weight of my 30kg engine,this is why am considering replacing its inlet with a surgical mask and to also increase the hp by 1.

Comment: What is your  basis this will increase hp?   A face mask have much different design parameters - it would be torn up.

Comment: What if I use an iron mesh to stregthen it@paparazzo

Comment: What if you looked for a high performance air filter?  Mesh is not going to strengthen the fiber.

Comment: Again what is you basis for more horse power?  Those filter to a very small size and not that easy to breath through.

Comment: According to honda website,removing the intake and exhaust of their gx engines will increase hp to about 2.5........so instead of leaving the intake open and expose the engine's delicate inware to dusk ....I thought about covering it with a mask.

Comment: I give up.  The mask is a filter and it is not even a high performance filter.

Comment: That's true tho

Comment: Exactly what is true?

Comment: That surgical masks are not high performance filters...not meant for air filtration for ICE @paparazzo

Comment: If you know a mask is not high performance then why do you assert an increase in HP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just plain silly.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Novel Idea' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/1832). Such questions tend to become moving targets and lead to discussions, neither of which are a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Air impurities are no issue for an ICE, only dust and other bigger particle matter are. The material of a surgical mask has little flow capacity, so a bigger filter is needed than normal, without good reason. You could use them for an ICE, but as is mentioned before, their flow capacity is way too low. You'd need to glue lots of them together, and fold them into a saw pattern to efficiently package them into a filter box. Then they could properly function as an airfilter.

But it won't weigh less, so it won't contribute in your search to lower the weight of your engine. If you don't live in a dusty area, rather remove the entire filter if it's really important for the engine to weigh less. The engine will wear faster though.

Answer (score 2):

How about the volume of air going through it?
For a human with assuming 10 breaths a minute and 2 litres per breath that is 40 litres a minute...

An engine will use that is seconds so the life of that filter is going to be very short.

Most racing engines don't have air filters as the servicing and rebuilds are so much more frequent, but for a family car then longevity is a higher priority.

Comment: What if i mesh the inlet with an iron guaze to strengthen the mask against the huge volume of air being sucked into the engine @Solar Mike

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to increase the airflow through a filter: bigger holes and more surface area.

Bigger holes is usually not possible because that would defeat the purpose of the filter. The face mask doesn't seal all that well to the face resulting in a few large holes at the side where air can escape and enter unfiltered.

More surface area ban be achieved by pleating the filter using a mesh to support it. You can buy ready made performance filters made for high airflow for not all that much money (a quick google found several for < $70) and that will be a better deal than trying to make your own.